# In a Bash for-loop, can I read the previous iteration's stdout as stdin?

Tags: bash, loops, imagemagick, pipe

I have a bash oneliner where I pipe one image through the same ImageMagick operation several times. I would like to do this as a Bash loop instead, preferably without using temp files.

The oneliner is: `cat in.jpg | convert -quality 1 - jpg:- | convert -quality 1 - jpg:- | convert -quality 1 - jpg:- > out.jpg`

This one also works: `(convert -quality 1 - jpg:- | convert -quality 1 - jpg:- | convert -quality 1 - jpg:-) > out.jpg < in.jpg`

In the `convert` command the `-` means "read from stdin" and `jpg:-` means "output in JPEG format to stdout".

I've tried doing `cat in.jpg | for x in {1..3}; do convert -quality 1 - jpg:-; done > out.jpg` and `(for x in {1..3}; do convert -quality 1 - jpg:-; done) < in.jpg > out.jpg`, but both give the same error.

I expect to get the output file with all 3 operations applied to it, but instead I get the output file with just one operation applied to it and the following errors, which I take to mean that the first iteration get to read the in.jpg file, but that the following iterations don't get anything on stdin:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ > error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `jpg:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `jpg:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

(I confirmed that it's only the first iteration that touches the output file by running `(for x in 90 30 1; do convert -quality $x - jpg:-; done) < in.jpg > out.jpg`

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do with that command?

Comment: I don't feel that I need to explain my art to you, Warren. 

Comment: @MarkSetchell All jokes aside, I'm exploring interesting compression artefacts for artistic and/or comedic purposes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Experimenting however shows that ImageMagick is to smart to recompress an image when saved with the same quality as it already had. Adding in an intermediate PNG conversion helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a recursive function:

```
rec_convert () {
  n=$1
  if [ $n -eq 0 ]; then
    cat
  else
    convert -quality 1 - jpg:- | rec_convert $((n - 1))
  fi
}

rec_convert 3 < in.jpg > out.jpg
```

Comment: Cool - love it!

Comment: Oh! So elegant!

Comment: Be aware, this probably isn't suitable for large values of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ugly construction (I don't like the `eval`), but will solve your problem:

```
cmd=()
for i in {1..3}
do
    cmd+=("convert" "-quality" "1" "-" "jpg:-" "|")
done
unset "cmd[${#cmd[@]}-1]"

eval "< in.jpg ${cmd[@]} > out.jpg"
```

You create an array calles `cmd`. Then, you use a loop to add to the array the components of your command and the pipe symbol. After creating this array, you drop the last element (an extra pipe that won't be needed). Finally, you `eval` the contatenation of the input redirection, the command line created and the output redirection.

The `eval` is needed because otherwise, the `|` is considered as a literal and does not create a pipe but is passed as arcument to `convert`.

Comment: Ha ha, same idea!

Comment: moot point, but if you want to avoid the eval you could pipe the text to `| bash`. Six of one, half-dozen of the other, as my grandfather used to say.

Comment: You are right, I can exchange an eval for an extra process started :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="cat input.jpg "
for ((iter=0;iter<15;iter++)) do
   cmd+=" | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- "
done
echo $cmd
bash -c "$cmd" > result.jpg
```

The debug output of the actual command executed is:

```
cat input.jpg | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:- | convert jpg:- -quality 50 jpg:-
```

Comment: An array is better, but `bash -c` seems like a good plan to me.

Answer (score 0):

And another method using `eval`:

```
# wrap command to be run into a shell function
# it should read from stdin and write to stdout
pipecmd(){ convert -quality 1 - jpg:-; }

# generate appropriate number of copies
cmds=()
for x in {1..3}; do cmds[$x]=pipecmd; done

# flatten list into a single string
cmdlist="${cmds[@]}"

# insert the pipes
pipeline="${cmdlist// /|}"

# create a shell function that uses this pipeline
# we need eval so $pipeline is expanded properly
eval "runpipeline(){ $pipeline; }"

# or combine the previous two steps
eval "runpipeline2(){ ${cmdlist// /|}; }"

# check what we created
type pipecmd
type runpipeline
type runpipeline2

# do something
runpipeline <in.jpg >out.jpg

# this will hang!
runpipeline in.jpg >out.jpg

# or just use the wrapped command directly
pipecmd <in.jpg | pipecmd | pipecmd >out.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to capture the intermediate output, you could use `<<<` and `$()`

Note that internally bash does use a temporary file for this, but at least you don't have to do the faff, but with the usual caviats if your content contains quotes:

```
res1=$(cmd1)
res2=$(cmd2 <<< "$res1" )
res3=$(cmd3 <<< "$res2" )
```